# A cartoon with monsters that looks like Gorillaz

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember that in the show a guy was friend of a couple of monsters that live with him in an attic. I remember that the art of the show was like Gorillaz, like realistic but with shadows. It was creepy for a child of 7 years.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was the "guy" a man or a boy, and what did the monsters look like?

Comment: Hi, I don't remember much because I was so small. But the boy was a teenager and the monsters were very sinister. I remember the monsters talking to the protagonist but it sounds to me that people couldn't see them.